# Allow a customer to order more then one of a product

Tags: opencart

**We do not want to limit the number of items a person orders.**  Our products are all priced the same based on size.  The only way I have found to do this with Opencart is by giving them an item a price of zero and controlling the price by using options.

Our problem is a user can not purchase more than one of an item.  This may or may not be related to the option condition mentioned above.

**EXAMPLE**: Say the product is a t-shirt and we want the size to be an option.  The customer would choose a design then a size.  Then quantity and checkout.

- Model number is the design.
- The price is based upon size.

**PROBLEM**:  Customer is limited to one t-shirt per model. In order words they can not order two size smalls of the same design.

Comment: I don't think this question is on-topic here. You may want to try http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/77558/opencart

Answer (score 0):

Your problem does have a solution. You can order more than 1 size of the same design. I see that your problem is when you add the item on your shopping bag.  When you go to checkout/cart page, there is a quantity column where in you can modify the quantity of your order.

Comment: Yes it says "1"  it will not allow us to change it to "2".

Comment: you can change it.
go to catalog > view > theme > default > template > checkout and look for cart.tpl

look for this code below:

***<input type="text" name="quantity[<?php echo $product['key']; ?>]" value="<?php echo $product['quantity']; ?>" size="1" class="checkout-quantity"/></span>***

Comment: ok.  code found.  Not sure I understand the solution.  Are you implying that I should change the code in some way?

Comment: yes, you have to change the code. Can you paste that code you have so that I could check?. Or better if you can paste here the code for cart.tpl, so that I could clearly see your page.

Comment: <td class="quantity"><input type="text" name="quantity[<?php echo $product['key']; ?>]" value="<?php echo $product['quantity']; ?>" size="1" />

this part of your code is correct. Why you can't change the value of 1 to other qty?